# drupal 7: How to create a pop-up window with close button, that shows automatically while loading front page

Tags: 7, webforms

I am struggling to create a pop-up window (webform, node or something else) with close button.

Modal forms can achieve this by click link. But anyone know how to make it shows without link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Lightbox2](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module. This might help you or else you can also try [Node pop-up](https://www.drupal.org/project/npop) module.